# How can I get a MMYYYY format in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

Okay, the question is mildly misleading...  I know a couple different ways to get the MMYYYY format from a date, but it requires converting the string into VARCHAR.  While that's all fine and dandy, ordering the results is where it becomes a real pain.

Here's what I'm using:

```
SELECT  
CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),MONTH(TransactionDte)) + '/' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(4),YEAR(TransactionDte) AS MMYYYY  
,SUM(TransactionCt) AS TransCt  
,SUM(TransactionAmt) AS TransAmt  
FROM Transactions  
GROUP BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),MONTH(TransactionDte)) + '/' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(4),YEAR(TransactionDte)
```

The results appear as follows:
1/2010
1/2011
10/2010
10/2011
11/2010
11/2011
12/2010
12/2011
2/2010
2/2011
3/2010
3/2011
etc...

I'm trying them to order by the date ascending.  As you can see, they do not...  Is there a way to get what I'm trying to achieve?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: why can't you just order by `TransactionDte`? Does your query have a `DISTINCT` or something?

Comment: I am using aggregate functions on other fields, so I cannot group by TransactionDte.  Doing so will create a row for each day of the month, where I want the results totaled for the entire month.

Comment: Well in that case you can order by `MIN(TransactionDte)` or  `MAX(TransactionDte)` then. See my answer for an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
;WITH t AS
(
SELECT GETDATE() AS TransactionDte UNION ALL 
SELECT GETDATE()+1 AS TransactionDte UNION ALL 
SELECT GETDATE()+90
)
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),MONTH(TransactionDte)) + '/' + 
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(4),YEAR(TransactionDte)) AS MMYYYY,
       COUNT(*)
FROM t
GROUP BY MONTH(TransactionDte), YEAR(TransactionDte)
ORDER BY MIN(TransactionDte)
```

Comment: @Abe - It's the OP's date formatting code I'm just demonstrating how to deal with aggregates as they describe in the comments.

Comment: No worries! Just regretting not putting my earlier comment as an answer!

Answer (score 5):

what is wrong with

```
ORDER BY TransactionDte DESC
```

or even

```
order by  CONVERT(VARCHAR(4),YEAR(TransactionDte) + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),MONTH(TransactionDte)) DESC
```

Comment: Because the resulting value is varchar, it does not order in terms of date.  It orders in terms of Alpha Numeric.  Please see the results I have posted and you'll see why it doesn't work.

Comment: Zach, "TransactionDte" isn't the result of your concatenation.

Comment: TransactionDte is the original column not what you convert it to

Comment: Sorry, I noticed after I replied.  Either way, if I order by the transactiondte, it wants it to be grouped by it as well, and if I group by transaction date, it returns a row for every transactiondte.

Answer (score 3):

Try this method:

```
    RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), TransactionDte, 103), 7) AS [MM/YYYY]
```

If you want it without the `/` then use this:

```
    REPLACE(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), TransactionDte, 103), 7),'/','') AS [MMYYYY]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
MM/YYYY
,TransCt
,TransAmt
FROM
(SELECT  
DATEPART(MM, TransactionDte) AS TransMonth
,DATEPART(YYYY,TransactionDte) AS TransYear
,RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), TransactionDte, 103), 7) AS [MM/YYYY]
,SUM(TransactionCt) AS TransCt  
,SUM(TransactionAmt) AS TransAmt  
FROM Transactions  
GROUP BY 
DATEPART(MM, TransactionDte) 
,DATEPART(YYYY,TransactionDte) AS TransYear
,RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), TransactionDte, 103), 7)
) T
ORDER BY TransYear,TransMonth
```